# I can't add tab to string In SSIS vb script task.Tab somehow got replaced with spaces

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting, stringbuilder, ssis-2012, chr

I've SQL Server Integration Services package with script task which create formatted string for message body. I use StringBuilder which appends text, appends Tabs (Chr(9)) and appends lines to format message. But when i assign final StringBuilder object to my string variable all tabs are replaced with spaces.
{

```
Dim EmailBody As New StringBuilder

Dim CoCd As String = RsWrongAltAccounts.Fields("CoCd").Value.ToString
Dim Accounts As String = RsWrongAltAccounts.Fields("AltAcct").Value.ToString
Dim FileName As String = RsWrongAltAccounts.Fields("FileName").Value.ToString

EmailBody.Append(CoCd) : EmailBody.Append(Chr(9))
EmailBody.Append(Accounts) : EmailBody.Append(Chr(9), 2)
EmailBody.Append(FileName) : EmailBody.AppendLine()

Dts.Variables("MessageText").Value = EmailBody.ToString
```

}
Already tried to use vbTab, "\t" instead of Chr(9) and different variations of 
{

```
AppendFormat("{0}\t {1}\t {3}", RsWrongAltAccounts.Fields("CoCd").Value.ToString, 
RsWrongAltAccounts.Fields("AltAcct").Value.ToString, 
RsWrongAltAccounts.Fields("FileName").Value.ToString)
```

}
Also set "Keep tabs" in Tools -> Options ->  Text Editor -> All Languages -> Tabs because don't know what else to do. So help heeded, please.

Comment: Certainly "\t" is meaningless in VB. You should be using `ControlChars.Tab`. That said, if `vbTab` is also not working, I'm not sure what is going on and I'm not in a position to test right now. On another note, those calls to `ToString` within `AppendFormat` are pointless. That will be done implicitly already. That's why those parameters are type `Object`.

Comment: Thank you  jmcilhinney. I tryed ControlChars.Tab as well with no success.It looks like some external configuration of SSIS scripting task prevent using tabs inside string.